# Javascript Object Composing

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering what the difference, or if any, the following JS is for building up an object. Is it a style thing/standards thing? If so, which is most common?

Example 1:

```
var MyNamspace = {
  options: { test: 10 },
  someFunction: function() { alert("Hello"); }
}
```

Example 2:

```
var MyNamespace = {};
MyNamespace.options = { test: 10 };
MyNamespace.someFunction = function() { alert("Hello"); }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no significant difference between the two (although the second is probably marginally slower).

The first example is more usual.

Answer (score 2):

The first `MyNamspace` is missing an "e", else there is no functional difference.

The second pattern is used when there is already an object with properties (like `someFunc.prototype`) which you want to extend, but you'd need to leave the overwriting part (`MyNamespace = {};`) away.

Answer (score 1):

The second option modifies an existing type, so while equal, the second is modifying the signature of an existing type, just like you could do: `MyClass.prototype.someFunction = function() { }`

This is where JavaScript can be conveniently flexible.